# FreeForm - Limit number of fields/columns in Form Builder

Tags: plugin-freeform

Is there a way to limit how many columns/fields a user is allowed to drag/add into the form builder. Currently, they are allowed to line up 4 in a row. I would like to limit that to 2. But I would specifically like to restrict the Form Builder so unfortunately fixing this via templates/CSS won't work.